# PHP: mkdir on buttonclick?

Tags: php, mkdir

i sort of want to create a little backend of a small website. i wonder how i make a button that creates a folder on my server?

mkdir should work! however how can i trigger the mkdir event on a buttonclick?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes -- you will have to either submit with the button click or use AJAX (I suggest using a javascript library such as jQuery). That will then get you on the server side where you can execute `mkdir()`.